# Pipe arguments to hunspell with xargs

Tags: xargs, hunspell

I'm trying to run hunspell over my source tree. However when I run this:

```
find . -name *.html | xargs hunspell -H
```

The Hunspell editor comes up on the screen, but it won't accept any typed input - all of the input appears at the next command prompt when I type Ctrl+C to exit the hunspell editor. Is there a way I can pipe files to hunspell?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but this seems like a ServerFault question.

Comment: I added: http://serverfault.com/questions/376316/how-can-i-run-hunspell-on-a-list-of-files-with-xargs

Comment: it looks like std input for hunspell is also the pipe, but the pipe is emptied by xargs, so hunspell doesn't get anything. Not sure how to solve it at this point, will give you an answer if I find one, or find it's not doable ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on an answer by [nosid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305501/nosid) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223296/how-to-prompt-a-user-from-a-script-run-with-xargs).

```
xargs -a <(find . -name *.html) hunspell -H
```

see nosid's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223296/how-to-prompt-a-user-from-a-script-run-with-xargs) for an explanation (: