# how to prompt a user from a script run with xargs

Tags: bash, xargs

I'm using xargs to populate the arguments to a script in which I want to stop the script, waiting for user input. Something like:

```
echo a b c | xargs bash -c 'for a in "$@"; do echo $a; read; done'
```

but the `read` gets ignored. It seems that the second script is trying to get it's input from the pipe too? I've tried `xargs -p` but it's no better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the option `-a` is given to `xargs`, the arguments will be read from a file instead of stdin. You can use bash's *process substitution* with the syntax `<( ... )` to create the *file* on the fly.

```
xargs -a <( echo A B C ) bash -c 'for x in "$@"; do echo $x; read; done'
```

Note that here`$@`misses the first argument ('A' in this case). This is because `bash -c` puts 'A' into `$0` (which normally takes the name of the script file), and `$@` provides `$1`, `$2` etc... (in this case 'B' and 'C').

Comment: wonderful! Thanks (:  An interesting note: "$@" here catches 'b' then 'c'. 'a' is stored in $0, 'b' in $1 etc..

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, which doesn't rely on Bash but on [GNU's flavor of xargs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils), is to use the `-o` or `--open-tty` option:

```
echo a b c | xargs --open-tty bash -c 'for a in "$@"; do echo $a; read; done'
```

From the manpage:

```
-o, --open-tty
       Reopen  stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before executing the command.  This is use‐
       ful if you want xargs to run an interactive application.
```