# xargs can't get user input?

Tags: linux, shell

i have a sample code like this:

```
CMD="svn up blablabla | grep -v .tgz"
echo $CMD | xargs -n -P ${PARALLEL:=20} -- bash -c
```

the purpose is to run svn update in parallel. However when encounter the conflicts, which should prompt out several selection for users to choose, it just passes without waiting for user input. And an error is shown:

```
Conflict discovered in 'blablabla'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
    (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
    (s) show all options: svn: Can't read stdin: End of file found
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that svn's stdin is not a console. It is the input of xargs, i.e. the output of the echo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to fix this! See the answer to [how to prompt a user from a script run with xargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223296/how-to-prompt-a-user-from-a-script-run-with-xargs). Long story short, use

```
xargs -a FILENAME your_script
```

or

```
xargs -a <(cat FILENAME) your_script
```

The first version actually reads lines from a file, and the second one fakes reading lines from a file, which is convenient for using xargs in pipe chains with awk or perl. Remember to use the -0 flag if you don't want to break on whitespace!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which doesn't rely on Bash but on [GNU's flavor of xargs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils), is to use the `-o` or `--open-tty` option:

```
echo $CMD | xargs -n -P ${PARALLEL:=20} --open-tty -- bash -c
```

From the manpage:

```
-o, --open-tty
       Reopen  stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before executing the command.  This is use‐
       ful if you want xargs to run an interactive application.
```